# Adding Js add-in to Custom Ribbon Tab created by VSTO add-in

Tags: office-js, word-addins

Is it possible to add new Js Add-in buttons to our old Custom Ribbon created by VSTO add-in. From what i have read and tried it should work as  it worked on standard tabs.
Also is it possible to add it to existing group tried so far hasn't worked.

Thanks in advance
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

no this is not supported. you can only add commands to a brand new tab or any existing OOB tab.

Comment: Hello, @Juan Balmori, I know that this question is almost 5 yrs. old, but I was wondering: Would your answer to this question still be the same today? Is there no supported way to combine VSTO and OfficeJs buttons into a single ribbon tab? Thanks.